# Linking Intel Fortran with Visual Studio for ANSYS UPF

Tags: visual-studio, dll, linker, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to use User Programmable Features (UPF) in ANSYS 18.0. In order to do that, ANSYS recommends using Intel Fortran 15.0.2 and Visual Studio 2012. Since Visual Studio 2012 is no more available on Microsoft Website to download, I am using following software -

**MS Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (Update 3), Intel Parallel Studio XE 17.0.4, ANSYS 18.0.**

After installing these as suggested in different tutorials/ forums, I try to compile a simple "Hello World" code from Visual Studio 2015. It worked (as in the screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0udk.jpg). It seems like Intel Fortran has been integrated properly with Visual Studio.

I have been following this link - https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/17.0/en-us/help/ans_prog/a9yI4r32wfl.html (process **1.10.3. Using the ANS_ADMIN Utility**) to accomplish integration with ANSYS.

To create custom ANSYS.exe, I kept the file to be compiled and linked in following directory - *C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v180\ansys\custom\user\winx64* and then set the user environment variable as in the screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/t38JG.jpg.

Then I went on to compile my desired UPF using visual studio 2015 command prompt in administrator mode. First, I changed the directory to *C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v180\ansys\custom\user\winx64* and then issued **ANSCUST.BAT** command. The output is shown in this screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9dKo.jpg (The system can't find the path specified).

Still, I continued and it showed me the desired Fortran file is being compiled - https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ujs.jpg.

After a while, this returned a linking error, LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libdecimal.lib' - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ5dv.jpg.

I also tried the process **1.10.2. Creating a Dynamic-link (DLL) Library** from the ANSYS documentation linked above. The returned output is here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMdkS.jpg.

If the issue is being created from the fact that, ANSYS is not compatible with the versions of other software, then I can update ANSYS version. But I think, this issue is an integration problem. Can you please help me solving the issue?